# Making a div element pop out it's parent that has overflow:auto

Tags: html, css, menu, overflow, z-index

Is there any way to make `.bar` pop up out of bounds of `.foo` and `.plaa` and over `.baz` in the following example:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uz9swktn/6/)

HTML:

```
<div class="plaa">
    <div class="foo">
        FOO
        <div class="bar">
            BAR
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
<div class="baz">
    BAZ
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.bar{
    display:none;
    width:420px;
    height:420px;
    background-color:pink;
    z-index:420;
    position:absolute;
    overflow:auto;

}
.foo{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:orange;
    cursor:pointer;
    position:relative;

}
.baz{
    position:absolute;
    top:55px;
    background-color:yellow;
}
.plaa{
    position:absolute;
    overflow:auto;
    max-width:50px;
    max-height:50px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(".foo").click(function(){$(".bar").toggle()});
```

It works fine when I remove `overflow:auto;` from `.plaa` but unfortunately I can't do that in my real world case.

Answer (score 0):

Make these change

```
.plaa{
position:absolute;
max-width:50px;
max-height:50px;
```

}

```
$(".foo").click(function(){$(".bar").toggle(function(){$(".bar").css({"overflow":"visible"});})});
```

I hope this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

if you really can't do that in real world case then manipulate the DOM using javascript.